# Change swiper left/right buttons's position React native

Tags: react-native

I'm using React native Swiper and i would like to change the position of left/right buttons from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

only the buttons not the dots,my code looks like this:

```
<Swiper  showsButtons={true} paginationStyle={{bottom: undefined, left: undefined, top:35, right:"47%"}}>
<View>
.
.
.
</View>
</Swiper
```

i'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BAD WAY**

In react-native-swiper/src/index.js

```
buttonWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
```

Change the buttons style by

```
buttonWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  },
```

And adjust like you want

**EDIT: GOOD WAY**

I just saw that you can use the buttonWrapperStyle props

```
<Swiper buttonWrapperStyle={{alignItems: 'flex-start'}} showsButtons={true} paginationStyle={{bottom: undefined, left: undefined, top:35, right:"47%"}}>
...
</Swiper>
```

Comment: thank you sir for the help! it worked but it changed all the swiper on my app, and i only want to change it on one,i trierd adding buttonwrapper to <Swiper> but it didn't work

Comment: I edited my answer with the good way and that solve your problem

Comment: perfect this is what i look for